# Map Reduce: Why does this code give the correct output for max but not min?

Tags: mapreduce, python-2.x

I am testing some map reduce code in Ubuntu, python 2 with commmand:

```
 cat testfile2 | ./mapper.py  | sort | ./reducer.py
```

I get the correct output for max but not min, ever time I get the value 1 for min as though it hasn't changed from it's original value. Every single value 'value' is less than 1 so on the first iteration through the for loop min should change to the first value and then update the min on further iterations. Am I loosing my mind or is there a silly mistake in the code? Please help!

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import sys

def reducer():
    max = 0
    min = 1
    old_tuple = ('foo', 'bar')
    i = 0

    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")

        if len(data) != 3:
            continue

        city, year, value = data
        new_tuple = (city, year)

        if old_tuple != new_tuple:
            if i != 0:
                print "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(old_tuple[0], old_tuple[1], max, min)            
                max = 0
                min = 1
        i += 1    
        old_tuple = new_tuple
        if min > value:
            min = value

        if max < value:
            max = value 


    if old_tuple != ('foo', 'bar'):
         print "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(old_tuple[0], old_tuple[1], max, min) 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    reducer()
```

The output I get looks like so

```
Alert   2009    0.215236752 1
Winnipeg    2017    0.032557214 1
```

Comment: Python is not my language, but it seems that you forgot to convert string `value` to float. Without such conversion, comparison is performed lexicographically and not numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I was using min and max as variable names that are keywords. After changing

```
min => minimum 
max => maximum
```

the output was still incorrect. The same problem actually. It was only after attempting to get the min and max in a more Pythonic way that I got it working. I'm new to Python so this may still be not the best most Pythonic way but the code below is at least getting the min and max values as needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import math

def reducer():
    list_ = []
    old_tuple = ('foo', 'bar')
    i = 0

    for line in sys.stdin:
        data = line.strip().split("\t")

        if len(data) != 3:
            continue

        city, year, value = data
        new_tuple = (city, year)

        if old_tuple != new_tuple:
            if i != 0:
                print "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(old_tuple[0], old_tuple[1], max(list_), min(list_))        
                list_ = []    

        i += 1 
        list_.append(value)   
        old_tuple = new_tuple

    if old_tuple != ('foo', 'bar'):
         print "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}".format(old_tuple[0], old_tuple[1], max(list_), min(list_)) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    reducer()
```